# Display figure in Jupyter notebook generated using bare matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

Using **Jupyter notebook** and I can generate a figure using **Pyplot**'s *stateful* (procedural) approach:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.figure( "spam" )
axis = fig.add_subplot()
axis.set_title( "beans" )
```

Somewhat annoyingly this displays without being asked to, but it does display with a very nice GUI:

[image]

When I try to reproduce this behaviour with an image generated using **Matplotlib**'s *stateless* (OOP) approach however, I lose the nice GUI:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot
import matplotlib.figure
fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(  )
axis = fig.add_subplot()
axis.set_title( "beans" )
fig.canvas.set_window_title( "spam" )
fig
```

[image]

Is there some way to include the nice GUI for images generated using `matplotlib` (and not `matplotlib.pyplot`)?

I don't mind invoking `pyplot` *after* the figure is created, but I would like to display figures that come from a library (and therefore created using the OOP approach) in a Jupyter notebook.